# Circle Through Three Points

Tags: code-golf, math

Given the Cartesian coordinates of three points on a plane, find the equation of the circle through them all. The three points will not be on a straight line.

Each line of input to your program will contain the `x` and `y` coordinates of three points, in the order `A(x),A(y),B(x),B(y),C(x),C(y)`. These coordinates will be real numbers less than 1,000,000 separated from each other by space.

The solution is to be printed as an equation of the form `(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2`. Values for `h`, `k`, `r` are to be printed with three digits after the decimal point. Plus and minus signs in the equations should be changed as needed to avoid multiple signs before a number.

```
Sample Inputs

7.0 -5.0 -1.0 1.0 0.0 -6.0
1.0 7.0 8.0 6.0 7.0 -2.0

Sample Outputs

(x - 3.000)^2 + (y + 2.000)^2 = 5.000^2
(x - 3.921)^2 + (y - 2.447)^2 = 5.409^2
```

Comment: Can we use polar or parametric equations instead?

Comment: @peter No. That way it will be difficult to compare with other answers.

Comment: What should be output in the case that there isn't a unique solution? What constraints are there on numerical robustness?

Comment: @peter-taylor It is given in the problem statement that 'The three points will not be on a straight line.'

Comment: @fR0DDY, I asked two questions...

Comment: @peter-taylor Sorry, I missed that. I will add that.

Comment: Does the output have to be exactly like your example (i.e. do we have to print all the whitespace)?

Comment: @ventero Do not worry about the spaces, but yes the rest of the format should be the same.

Comment: Granted, it is only a few characters so this isn't a rant that my solution could be a few shorter, just an honest question...but if whitespace is in the output spec, shouldn't it be mandatory?  Otherwise, in a code-golf, why would anyone meet the output spec?

Answer (score 6):

### Python, <strike>176</strike> 189 chars

```
import sys,re
for s in sys.stdin:x,y,z=eval(re.sub(r'(\S+) (\S+)',r'\1+\2j,',s));w=z-x;w/=y-x;c=(x-y)*(w-abs(w)**2)/2j/w.imag-x;print'(x%+.3f)^2+(y%+.3f)^2=%.3f^2'%(c.real,c.imag,abs(c+x))
```

Does all its work in the complex plane.  I go the math from the bottom of [this page](http://www.math.okstate.edu/~wrightd/INDRA/MobiusonCircles/node4.html).  `-c` is the center of the circle.

Comment: @Joey: yep, my bad.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 192 characters

```
$<.map{|l|a,b,c,d,e,f=l.split.map &:to_f
n=(f-d)/(e-c)
puts"(x%+.3f)^2+(y%+.3f)^2=%.3f^2"%[x=-(n*(a+c)+(n*(b-f)-(c+e))*m=(d-b)/(c-a))/2/n-=m,y=-(x+(a+c)/2)/m-(b+d)/2,((a+x)**2+(b+y)**2)**0.5]}
```

Usage examples:

```
$ echo "7.0 -5.0 -1.0 1.0 0.0 -6.0
1.0 7.0 8.0 6.0 7.0 -2.0" | ruby circle.rb
(x-3.000)^2+(y+2.000)^2=5.000^2
(x-3.921)^2+(y-2.447)^2=5.409^2
```

Comment: Inlining the assignments to `x`, `y` and `r` in the call to `%` should help, if possible.

Comment: @Joey: Sorry, apparently missed that when reading the question. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

#### C# - 490

```
using System;class C{static void Main(){Func<string,double>p=s=>double.Parse(s);Func<double,string>t=s=>(s<0?"+ ":"- ")+Math.Abs(s).ToString("F3");foreach(var l in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("i")){var v=l.Split();double a=p(v[0]),b=p(v[1]),c=p(v[2]),d=p(v[3]),e=p(v[4]),f=p(v[5]),m=(d-b)/(c-a),n=(f-d)/(e-c),x=(m*n*(b-f)+n*(a+c)-m*(c+e))/(2*(n-m)),y=-(x-(a+c)/2)/m+(b+d)/2,r=Math.Sqrt((x-a)*(x-a)+(y-b)*(y-b));Console.WriteLine("(x "+t(x)+")^2+(y "+t(y)+")^2 = "+r.ToString("F3")+"^2");}}}
```

This finds the 2 lines between AB and BC.  Then it finds where the bisects of those 2 lines intersect.  (Which I just noticed is what @PeterTaylor mentioned in his comment to @PeterOfTheCorn.)

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (299)

The only way that I could think of solving this was algebraically solving three equations for three unknowns to find h, k, and r.

```
p=prompt().split(' ');a=p[0],b=p[1],c=p[2],d=p[3],e=p[4],f=p[5];h=((a*a+b*b)*(f-d)+(c*c+d*d)*(b-f)+(e*e+f*f)*(d-b))/(a*(f-d)+c*(b-f)+e*(d-b))/2;k=((a*a+b*b)*(e-c)+(c*c+d*d)*(a-e)+(e*e+f*f)*(c-a))/(b*(e-c)+d*(a-e)+f*(c-a))/2;r=Math.sqrt((a-h)*(a-h)+(b-k)*(b-k));alert("(x-"+h+")²+(y-"+k+")²="+r+"²");
```

Example I/O:

`7.0 -5.0 -1.0 1.0 0.0 -6.0` --> `(x-3)²+(y--2)²=5²`

`1.0 7.0 8.0 6.0 7.0 -2.0` --> `(x-3.9210526315789473)²+(y-2.4473684210526314)² =5.409159155551175²`

The only bug that I see is that if h or k is negative, it outputs `--` instead of `+`.

Comment: It can be done with compass and straight edge. Take two points, draw the line which bisects them. Take a different pair of two points, ditto. Find the intersection. Whether that leads to shorter code, I have yet to investigate.

Comment: This handles only a single line of input, right?

Comment: @Joey, yes. Does the problem require multiple line handling?

Comment: Quoting from the task: »Each line of input to your program will contain the x and y coordinates of three points ...«